# Gimp menu shortcuts and Toolbox

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gimp, toolbar

In most Gimp tools the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is used for some command. How can I use menu shortcuts, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>", if some tool is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You just use them.

The fact that this triggers something for the tool - usually a mode change - shouldn't interfere, and it doesn't do that for me.